# calculate a new variable with random numbers

Tags: r, dataframe, random

I’m pretty sure that the solution to my problem must be VERY easy, but I really got stuck in this.

A simple df:

```
df <- data.frame(
  "v1" = c(0.1, 0.2,0.6,0.8))
```

I want to calculate a new variable that is a random number from a uniform distribution with `min = 0` and `max = v1`.
I’m using `runif()`, but I got the same result for each value of the new variable.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you actually mean ```min=0 and max=v1``` or maybe ```min=0 and max=max(v1)``` or even ```min=0 and max=v1``` (rowwise)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `runif` as :

```
df$v2 <- runif(nrow(df), min = 0, max = df$v1)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(v2 = runif(n(), min = 0, max = v1))
```